# How come? aliases not detected in trait

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, type-alias

The question is simple: look at the code. Both static asserts pass. I would not expect the second one to pass. Is this a bug or normal behavior?

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <class...> class Temp, class Specialization>
struct IsSpecialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Temp, class... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<Temp, Temp<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template <class...Args>
struct A {};

template <class...Args>
using AT = A<Args...>;


int main() {
    static_assert(IsSpecialization<A, A<int>>{});
    static_assert(!IsSpecialization<AT, AT<int>>{});
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, "specialization" is the correct term.

Comment: I confirm the behavior for my clang++ (3.8.1) but my g++ (6.3.0) fail the second `static_assert()`

Comment: @max66 is this a bug?

Comment: I suspect it but I wait for opinions from standard gurus.

Comment: @T.C. So it is.

Comment: So unfortunate, I need a workaround :( @FrançoisAndrieux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Temp` is deduced twice when you try to match the partial specialization:

- By matching `Temp` against `AT`. This trivially deduces `Temp` to be `AT`.
- By matching `Temp<Ts...>` against `AT<int>`. This deduces `Temp` to be `A` because `AT<int>` is equivalent to `A<int>`, and this deduction will never deduce an alias template (see [[temp.alias]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.alias#2)).

The overall deduction succeeds - and the partial specialization is a match - iff the two deductions give `Temp` the same value, i.e., iff `AT` and `A` are considered to be equivalent. Whether they are [is currently an open question](https://wg21.link/CWG1286).

Comment: So how could I get equivalent checks? P.S.: I know it is not my original question, I will accept this one. Now I understand why the different behavior in gcc/clang

Answer (score 2):

Not an explanation (see the T.C.'s answer for it) but a workaround: modify the true version of `IsSpecialization` as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class Temp1,
          template <typename...> class Temp2, typename... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<Temp1, Temp2<Ts...>>
   : public std::is_same<Temp1<Ts...>, Temp2<Ts...>>
 { };
```

T.C. explain that with your original code, `AT` is deduced as `AT` when seen as container and as `A<Ts...>` as type.

The trick is deduce `AT` and and `A` in different template-template argument, apply the same template types (`Ts...`) obtaining `AT<Ts...>` and `A<Ts...>`. But `AT<Ts...>` and `A<Ts...>` are the same type and `std::is_same` understand it.

Comment: Lol great! I was experimenting right now with std::is_same

Comment: I voted you up but I cannot accept your reply as the original question is why that happens. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Only works with ~transparent alias templates, but that's pretty much the best you can do here. +1

Comment: @GermánDiago - You've made the right thing: the T.C. answer is a correct answer for this question (and a great one); my answer is more a comment (but I hope is helpful).

Comment: @T.C. amazingly, this still fails for my real use case :( which is a slight modification of the above but should be at all effects identical in my mind.

Comment: @GermánDiago - your real use case alias fix some of the types; I mean: is something as `template <typename ... Ts> using foo = bar<int, Ts...>;`?

Comment: @T.C. there is a prepended tag plus the Ts... and the Ts... only appear in the alias but not the tag.

Comment: @GermánDiago - the not transparent alias template case (see the preceding comment from T.C.). Suggestion: modify your question (or create a new one) that show your real alias (or something simpler but similar) and show how do you want use your type traits (I mean... do you want a generic type traits or a type traits specific for deterct specializations of your alias?).